# Gauss application is an isometry

Tags: differential-geometry

My question is very simple :

> What can we say of a compact surface $\mathcal{S} \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ satisfying that the Gauss application $N$ is an isometry : $\mathcal{S} \to \mathbb{S}^2$

Despite the question is very simple I remain stuck on it and without any serious leads. I know that $N$ is then one to one and that for every $q \in \mathbb{S}^2$ there exists  $p \in \mathcal{S}$ such that the Gaussian curvature $K$ satisfies $K(p) \geqslant 0$ and $N(p)=q$. 
Then $\mathcal{S}$ satisfies $K \geqslant 0$. But I didn't use the asumption on $N$ saying that this map is an isometry ... My guess is that $\mathcal{S}$ is a sphere !

Being an isometry is equivalent as being one to one and a differential isometry : $\langle dN_p(u),dN_p(v)\rangle = \langle u,v \rangle $ for all $p \in \mathcal{S}$ and $u,v \in T_p \mathcal{S}$.

I would be glad if someone provides me some leads or begining of a solution. Thanks.

Comment: let $p=q$ for a start

Comment: Are you sure that's what is meant by saying that $N$ is an isometry?

Comment: I edited, I was mistaken on the definition of an isometry when it is the case of sub manifolds ...

Comment: @I think there is a problem with my definition of an isometry ...

Comment: OK, cool, now you've fixed it. :) Now think about what has to be true about the eigenvalues of the linear map $-dN_p$ (the so-called shape operator).

Comment: Such eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ satisfies $\lambda _i = \pm 1$ and $\lambda _1= \lambda _2$ so the surface is totally umpilical and then an open set of a sphere or plan ? Is it right ?

Comment: Sphere, not plane!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is now resolved :

Let $p\in \mathcal{S}$ and $\lambda$ and $\lambda_1(p),\lambda_2(p)$ the eigenvalues of $dN_p$ and $u_p,v_p$ aigenvectors associated. Thus with the hypothesis that $dN_p$ is an isometry it follows that $\lambda_1 \lambda _2 =1$.

Then there is two cases : $\lambda_1 (p)=\lambda _2 (p)=1$ or $\lambda _1 (p)=\lambda _2 (p)=-1$. Since $\lambda$ depends continuously on $p \in \mathcal{S}$ we deduce $\lambda _1 = \lambda _2 = 1$ or $\lambda _1 = \lambda _2 = -1$.

Thus $\mathcal{S}$ is totally umbilical, so $\mathcal{S}$ is an open set of a sphere of a plan. Since a plan have a zero Gauss curvature we deduce that $\mathcal{S}$ is a sphere.